# Symfony 2 registration form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a registration form in Symfony 2.4 following the guide here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

Lets say I've got 2 FormTypes

PersonType
RegistrationType

PersonType defines all the fields for a specific user.

```
// PersonType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName','text',['attr'=>['placeholder'=>'First Name']])
        ->add('lastName','text',['attr'=>['placeholder'=>'Last Name']])
        ->add('email','email',['attr'=>['placeholder'=>'email@example.com']])
        ->add('title','choice', ['choices'=>$this->titles, 'required'=>true])
        ->add('phone','text',['attr'=>['placeholder'=>'(555) 555-1234']])
        ->add('accountStatus')
        ->add('organization')
        ->add('address', 'text',['attr'=>['placeholder'=>'123 Fake St']])
        ->add('city')
        ->add('province','choice', ['choices'=>$this->provinces, 'required'=>true])
        ->add('postalCode','text',['attr'=>['placeholder'=>"A1A 1A1"]])
    ;
}
```

RegistrationType adds:

```
// RegistrationType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $person = new PersonType();
    $builder->add('person', $person);

    $builder->add('termsAccepted','checkbox');

    $builder->add('submit','submit', ['attr'=>['class'=>'btn-primary'], 'label' => "Submit Account Request"]);
}
```

The issue is - I don't want to include accountStatus on the registration form, as this will be set by code when I persist it to the database.  When I output my form it's including the accountStatus.

In Symfony 1.4 to pull this same thing off I simply extended the PersonForm, and unset any widgets I did not require.

Am I going about this wrong?  This is my first Symfony 2 project.

EDIT: I found the solution for my case.  I wanted accountStatus in my main form, but want to reuse everything except that for my registration form.
I simply added this to my form after rendering all the fields I wanted
{% do form.person.setRendered %}

Answer (score 0):

accountStatus is appearing in the form because of this line:

```
->add('accountStatus')
```

remove this line and you won't see it in the form.

Comment: I want it there though.  My intention is to use the PersonType form on one screen (an administrative screen), but use the RegistrationType form as a register form.